# How to pass data from Data flow activity to other activity in Azure data factory v2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have extracted a max date from the data in a Data flow activity, however, I am not able to pass it or set it to a variable so that other activities could use the same value. Please suggest how could it be done.

[image: Max date - data flow activity]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to persist it somewhere. Every data flow requires a Sink. Just drop it into a CSV file in Blob/ADLS. You don't even need a header or any other columns. Just store "12" or whatever your result it in that file. The next activity in your pipeline will then be a Lookup activity to get that value and use it in your pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for [cached lookups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HqCn42FaRJs), a feature added ~3 months or so after you asked this question.